# Puppetlabs-Apache: enable both 80 and 443 for virtualhost

Tags: apache, puppet, virtualhost, puppetlabs-apache

I'm relatively new to puppet and currently working on 'puppetlabs-apache' module. I'm missing something while setting both ssl and non-ssl on a virtual-host.

Manifest applied:

```
include apache
include apache::mod::rewrite

#apache::vhost { 'site.mydomain.com':
# port         => '80',
# docroot      => '/var/www/site',
# rewrite_rule => '(.*) https://site.mydomain.com [R,L]',
#}

apache::vhost { 'site.mydomain.com':
  port          => '443',
  ssl           => true,
  docroot       => '/var/www/site',
  docroot_owner => 'www-data',
  docroot_group => 'www-data',
#  rewrite_rule  => '(.*) https://site.mydomain.com [R,L]',
}
```

The thing is I don't need the non-ssl (80 port), but all requests should redirect to 443.

If I comment out the first `vhost` definition of `site.mydomain.com` for port 80, it throws an error:

> Error 400 on SERVER: Duplicate declaration: Apache::Vhost[site2.mydomain.com] is already declared in file..

Not sure what I'm missing here. What should I do to make this permanent redirect happen?

```
http://site2.mydomain.com/ => https://site2.mydomain.com/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To configure a virtual host to redirect unencrypted connections to SSL, declare them with separate `apache::vhost` defined types and redirect unencrypted requests to the virtual host with SSL enabled:

```
apache::vhost { 'site.mydomain.com:80':
  servername      => 'site.mydomain.com',
  port            => '80',
  docroot         => '/var/www/site',
  rewrite_rule    => '(.*) https://site.mydomain.com [R,L]',
  redirect_status => 'permanent',
  redirect_dest   => 'https://site.mydomain.com'
}

apache::vhost { 'site.mydomain.com:443':
  servername    => 'site.mydomain.com',
  port          => '443',
  ssl           => true,
  docroot       => '/var/www/site',
  docroot_owner => 'www-data',
  docroot_group => 'www-data',
  rewrite_rule  => '(.*) https://site.mydomain.com [R,L]',
}
```

You also needed those additional `redirect` attributes for the non-ssl virtualhost resource. Since `apache::vhost` is a defined resource type with no `namevar`, you can circumvent the multiple resource declaration issue by using two unique and purely cosmetic resource titles.

Comment: Thank you so much. I get the idea, but there is one slight problem with this.
This will create 2 virtualhost configurations
 [site.mydomain.com_ssl.conf, site.mydomain.com_non-ssl.conf]
with  **ServerName site.mydomain.com non-ssl** and **ServerName site.mydomain.com ssl**  ,
which will throw an error,

`AH00526: Syntax error on line 7 of /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/25-site.mydomain.com_non-ssl.conf:
ServerName takes one argument, The hostname and port of the server
`

Comment: @VineethVijayan This is literally how the documentation for `puppetlabs-apache` says to solve your problem. Either that conf file syntax error stems from elsewhere or the module itself has an issue. Which does it seem is more likely here?

Comment: The error made sense, and putting port instead there works..!!

`apache::vhost { 'site.mydomain.com:80' ... }

apache::vhost { 'site.mydomain.com:443' : ...} `

Comment: @VineethVijayan That sounds like a problem with the module. You may want to report it to the maintainer on Github. I will update the answer. I hope that doing a resource title with `servername:port` format does not create a messed up file name.

Comment: Thanks, let me see if I can report it.

Answer (score 0):

Working out Matt's answer and error while running it made me come at following answer.

```
apache::vhost { 'site.mydomain.com:80' ... } 

apache::vhost { 'site.mydomain.com:443' : ...}
```

Thanks,